# Cannot support both http and https url when running a ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to enable exposing a `ServiceHost` on both `HTTP` & `HTTPS`.

Here is the code that runs the service:

```
oServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(API), new Uri(WebHookURL))
oServiceHost.Open();
```

As you can see here - I'm getting the service URL (`WebHookURL`) during runtime. 
As mentioned, URL protocol can be either `HTTP` or `HTTPS`.

After lots of reading and testing, it came down to this `web.config` file:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="encryptingBinding" contract="ModuleComm.Commons.ServiceContracts.ModuleService" name="clientConf" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="myServiceWebServer.AsynchronousSocketListener">
        <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="encryptingBinding" contract="ModuleComm.Commons.ServiceContracts.ModuleService" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="API.Service1Behavior" name="myServiceWebServer.API">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="myServiceWebServer.IAPI" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="API.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />        
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="encryptingBinding">
          <!--  <messageEncryping /> -->
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
            <connectionPoolSettings leaseTimeout="23:59:00" maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="10000" />
          </tcpTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When trying to set `WebHookURL` (e.g: http://localhost:8111) to an `http` address - code works fine.

Unfortunately, when setting `WebHookURL` to an `https` address (e.g: **https**://localhost:8111) - code won't work and this exception is thrown when trying to create the `ServiceHost` instance:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].
```

What am I missing ?

**UPDATE 1:**

Tried this configurations but i'm getting configuration error:
Tried this but i'm getting configuration error:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>      
      <service behaviorConfiguration="API.Service1Behavior" name="WebServer.API">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="WebServer.IAPI" />
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBindingHTTPS" contract="WebServer.IAPI" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="API.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />        
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>      
      <wsHttpBinding>        
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="wsBindingHTTPS">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Better approach would be to put a webserver in front and terminate the SSL on server and then forward the request

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
   <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```

The `webHttpBinding` supports only ***HTTP*** requests and not ***HTTPS*** requests.
webHttpBinding does not support interoperability as well.

`WsHttpBinding` also supports interoperability. With this binding, the SOAP message is, by default, encrypted. It supports HTTP and HTTPS. In terms of encoding, it provides support for Text as well as MTOM encoding methods. It supports WS-* standards like WS-Addressing, WS-Security and WS-ReliableMessaging. By default, reliable sessions are disabled because it can cause a bit of performance overhead.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431291/WCF-Services-Choosing-the-appropriate-WCF-binding

So in order to use https, replace `webHttpBinding` with `WsHttpBinding`.

Here is a snippet that will match your solution:

1) Write two endpoints for the service, one is for http and another for https.

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="JK.MyService">

      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="JK.IMyService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>

      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBindingHTTPS" contract="JK.IMyService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>     

    </service>
  </services>
```

2) Enable both httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="true" in serviceBehaviors.

```
<behaviors>

<serviceBehaviors>      
  <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>      
</serviceBehaviors>

<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="WebBehavior">
    <webHttp/>
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

3) Write two bindings configurations for http and https. For http give security mode="None" and for https give mode="Transport".

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>

      <binding name="webBinding">
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>

      <binding name="webBindingHTTPS">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>

    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

Check this [link](http://jayakrishnagudla.blogspot.com/2009/12/configuring-wcf-services-to-work-with.html)

Comment: After I changed it to wsHttpBinding i'm getting this error when trying to use https:
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

Comment: added a snippet.

Comment: please take a look at "UPDATE 1".. still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<services>      
  <service behaviorConfiguration="API.Service1Behavior" name="WebServer.API">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="WebServer.IAPI" />
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBindingHTTPS" contract="WebServer.IAPI" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

In the endpoints defined in the configuration above, the value for binding is specified as `webHttpBinding`. However, the configuration provided for those bindings are defined for `wsHttpBinding`. Clearly there is a mismatch between the type of binding and its configuration. The below change should fix this error.

```
<services>      
  <service behaviorConfiguration="API.Service1Behavior" name="WebServer.API">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="WebServer.IAPI" />
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBindingHTTPS" contract="WebServer.IAPI" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Also in the below snippet, the `transport` element is redundant since the security mode is `None` and hence can be removed.

```
<binding name="webBinding">
  <security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
  </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: Tried to change to binding="wsHttpsBinding" and still it won't work. Please note that I have two kind of bindings (one of them is webHttpBinding) in "UPDATE1" configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea: Why not allow HTTPS requests ONLY and re-route http request into https request. If your web server has IIS then you may find [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/) useful

and bar http request can be done [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api)

we generally apply certificate on NLB Node(Network Load Balanced) and configure http to https route on all individual web servers

Answer (score 0):

actually its simple. all you need is one binding for http and another one for https like this:

```
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SoapBinding"  />
 </basicHttpBinding>
 <mexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MexBinding" />
 </mexHttpBinding>
 <mexHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="SecureMexBinding" />
 </mexHttpsBinding>
 <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="SecureSoapBinding"  />
 </basicHttpsBinding>
 <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RestBinding"  />
    <binding name="SecureRestBinding" >
     <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
 </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="myServiceWebServer.API">
            <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding" name="Soap" contract="myServiceWebServer.IAPI" />
            <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureSoapBinding" name="SecureSoap" contract="myServiceWebServer.IAPI" />
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" name="Rest" contract="myServiceWebServer.IAPI" />
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureRestBinding" name="SecureRest" contract="myServiceWebServer.IAPI" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MexBinding" name="Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureMexBinding" name="SecureMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: Unfortunately - after trying your suggested configurations i'm getting this error: "Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]."

Comment: well its simple. i guess you hosted  your application on iis. make sure you add both HTTP and HTTPS binding on your web site. or you can remove the soap bindings if you don't need them.